# why do i get invalid syntax at the fourth line?

Tags: python-3.x, min

```
def min (x,y):
    if x < y:
        return x
    else
         return y

min(7,5)
print min(7,5)
```

I am trying to use min function for practice. The function has to return the smallest number of the two numbers that are written above. And I get a syntax error at the fourth line, when else is written. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `:` in the fourth line. Your correct code would be:

```
def min (x,y):
    if x < y:
        return x
    else:
         return y

min(7,5)
print min(7, 5)
```

In Python3.x in the last line you would write

```
print(min(7, 5))
```

Actually, you also wouldn't need to re-declare the `min()` function. It is already built-in in python. Just write:

```
min(7,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit complicated for others to understand your code if you don't properly format for us to see each line where it's supposed to be, however I assume it's something like this, with a ":" you forgot:

```
def min (x,y):
    if x < y:
        return x 
    else:
        return y
```

And what you want to display would be:

```
print(min(7,5))
```

So you were missing a parenthisis that, unlike in Python 2, is neccesary in Python 3.

Anyways you may want to explore other possible outcomes when comparing numbers. Simple example:

```
def min (x,y):
    if x < y:
        return x 
    elif x > y:
        return y
    elif x == y:
        return "both are equal"
```